# What is the use of a static initialization block in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, geb

What is the use of the static initialization block in Groovy. Why does Geb use it? If the use of it is the same as in Java, then how can you initialize non-declared fields in a situtation like this?

```
class ManualsMenuModule extends Module { 
    static content = { 
        toggle { $("div.menu a.manuals") }
        linksContainer { $("#manuals-menu") }
        links { linksContainer.find("a") } 
    }

    void open() { 
        toggle.click()
        waitFor { !linksContainer.hasClass("animating") }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some answers to your questions are provided in the [section about the content DSL](http://gebish.org/manual/current/#content-dsl) of the Geb manual.

The DSL is implemented using [Groovy's `methodMissing()` mechanism](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_methodmissing) and modification of the [delegate](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_delegate_of_a_closure) of the closure assigned to the static `content` field. If you are interested in digging deeper then you can always look at the implementation in [`PageContentTemplateBuilder`](https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/f351d7e4e3753910e4902d321898d7e6bec96689/module/geb-core/src/main/groovy/geb/content/PageContentTemplateBuilder.groovy#L39).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert on Geb, I can only explain the groovy meaning of the code.

1st off, it's not the static initialization block like in java. In those lines `static content = {...}` you are assigning to a static variable a Closure instance which is evaluated and executed LATER (hence, `lazy`).

The closure represents a (part of) a Geb's Groovy Builder which is called by Geb framework to register/perform some tasks.

There's no Java counterpart to achieve the same, and that's the reason why groovy-based frameworks are so nice to use for testing purposes and they follow the general rule of thumb:

> test code should be more abstract then the code under test

UPDATE:

This line:

```
toggle { $("div.menu a.manuals") }
```

can be rewritten like

```
toggle( { $("div.menu a.manuals") } )
```

or

```
def a = { $("div.menu a.manuals") }
toggle a
```

so it's a method invocation and not an assignment. In groovy you can omit the brackets in some cases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @injecteer. So then the content variable is a closure of closures?(I mean what are 'toggle', 'linksContainer' and 'links' for) Or I'm wrong?

Comment: sort of. the `content` closure contains a builder code which might contain nested closures. see http://groovy-lang.org/dsls.html#_jsonbuilder as an example

Comment: And what do we call the following construction: "toggle { $("div.menu a.manuals") }"?

Comment: no idea )). I can only speculate, that some jquery-like selector is called

Comment: I mean "toggle { $("div.menu a.manuals") }" is  the same as "toggle({ $("div.menu a.manuals") });". So how can we call a method that is not defined?

Comment: that is the trick the builder is doing for you. It lets you call methods which do not exist in groovy or java sdk, but are relevant inside you domain, like geb or html. In the later you can write `div{ span{ p 'hello' } }`. Those method are not defined anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot @injecteer